# Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials - apache vs command line on OSX local environment

Tags: php, macos, apache, aws-sdk

I'm experiencing problems with the AWS SKD for PHP, when attempting to create an S3 Client.

My PHP script attempts to create the S3 Client as follows:

```
$client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'profile' => 'default'
    'region'  => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
]);
```

This should read my credentials file from `/Users/username/.aws/credentials`.

It **works** when I run my PHP script from the command line

It **fails** when I run my PHP script from within a PHP application via local apache webserver and a browser.

The error I receive is

```
Cannot read credentials from /.aws/credentials
```

Notice that it's trying to read from my root directory, not my user directory.

Having Googled this issue, several posts (like [this one](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/887#issuecomment-318715019)) indicate that the AWS SDK makes use of the `$HOME` variable. To test this I:

- ran `printenv` in my terminal, which returns `HOME=/Users/username`
- ran `getenv('HOME')` in a PHP script from the command line which returns `HOME=/Users/username`
- ran `getenv('HOME')` and `print $_SERVER['HOME']` in a PHP script via Apache and browser - **no output**

I think the solution must be to pass `$HOME` into my apache setup - how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but on Linux - Ubuntu. I hope these steps can be replicated on OSX.

I added the value of my $HOME variable in a SetEnv directive in my Apache vhost as follows:

```
SetEnv HOME "/home/ubuntu"
```

In your case it should be:

```
SetEnv HOME "/Users/username"
```

Then reload apache:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

After this change the SDK was looking for the credentials in the correct file but Apache did not have permissions to access it. I recieved an error "Cannot read credentials from /home/ubuntu/.aws/credentials".
So, I changed the ownership and permissions of the ~/.aws folder as follows:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data ~/.aws
sudo chmod 640 ~/.aws/config
sudo chmod 640 ~/.aws/credentials
```

Where www-data is the user for my Apache process.

On OSX the user for Apache would be "_www", so in case you have not set the permissions for Apache then do the following:

```
sudo chown -R username:_www ~/.aws
sudo chmod 640 ~/.aws/config
sudo chmod 640 ~/.aws/credentials
```

Comment: Fantastic, the file permission part is very important! Just you have one issue with the command, when I tried to put `-R` before `~/.aws` and run it, I got this error: `chown: -R: No such file or directory` after Googling the `-R` option, I found that it should be called after `chown`, so the correct command should be `sudo chown -R username:_www ~/.aws` - Everything else is working fine. Thank you.